# Vue.js Riddle - Append component from string HTML

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have the following problem - Imagine a web blog article, it has paragraphs of text and few in-text photos from the gallery.

I'm getting the text in an array of HTML strings.

for example :

```
{
 0 : '<p> text text text'<p>,
 1 : '<p> text text text </p>',
 2 : '<span class="embed" data-id="111"></span>',
 3 : '<p> text text text </p>,
}
```

**I output the html via `v-html` directive after joining it with `.join()`**

What I need to do is somehow replace the SPAN before outputing the HTML with a vue.js component for embeded photo, for ex.:

```
<EmbedPhoto :id="data-id" @click="toggleGallery()"></EmbedPhoto>
```

I'm having no luck so far, first I tried outputing it as simple RAW html, but realised quick that the directives won't work. Any thoughts on how to replace this string with a component in the exact same place where the span is?

Thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible to make the endpoint return the numeric '111' rather than the span markup?  I'm thinking if you could do that then in your component you could have a v-if off of the type of the value and if it is a string do the v-html logic, otherwise if it is numeric then compose the <EmbedPhoto> element.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up detecting if a string has 'kcode' in it with includes(),which is a class every embed's span has, then converted the string to dom node via jquery parseHtml, read the data attributes via .dataset and creating an object with a type key in the place of the string in the initial array, then simply using v-for and v-if, if its a type="embed" im using a vue component, if its a text string im just outputing it with v-html.